# Live video streaming from another website VLC

Tags: javascript, live-streaming

I am trying to live stream my computer stream on another website, to another website. I have tried using VLC to stream from a local server to another local server. When I live stream the video onto the website, it either has nothing, or has a strange green box that appears that has some small parts of my display. I don't know what else to change. Here is my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    background-color:black;
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <video src="http://192.168.1.16:8080" width=700 preload="auto"  type="video/ogg; codecs=theora"></video>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try first playing that URL in another VLC instance and take a look at the error messages to get a clue why it's failing to play in the browser.

If there are no errors in VLC's messages window, then it could be a limited bandwidth that's causing this issue. That's usually a cause when you see some parts of your video, but not the entire picture.